# selenium webdriver javascript queries

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, scroll, mocha.js

I have been recently using selenium webdriver (nodejs module) in combination with mocha, for writing automation tests and these are some of the issues that I faced

## Scrolling

```
driver.findElement()
```

returns false since it is not able to locate the element since it is not visible in the current window but somewhere below. Reading some blogs, I thought scrolling would solve the issue.But,I cant find an API in selenium that helps me scroll up,down,left,right in the browser. I tried using the

```
scrollBy(xDelta,yDelta)
```

method of javscript inside the it() clause, but it did not work either

## Reading the text of an element where the text gets updated dynamically from back end.

The text is not present in the text attribute of the DOM element. I have the element's xpath, So that is my only means of accessing the element.

I have two requirements

A.) I need to read and get the value of some elements in the html page and store it

B.) I need to read the element and assert it against some text

can you please tell me the webdriver nodejs API methods for performing the same.

## Waiting for a particular text

The text of the element that I am trying to read changes over time in response to various events. How do I programatically wait for a particular text using selenium webdriver's javascript API

I am new to selenium and though I found many discussions for the above questions, but they were all for other platforms of selenium such as java,etc; there is very less documentation for the nodejs platform of the selenium API . So please help me with the same

Much Thanks in advance

Comment: The scrolling issue and the text issues are substantially **different questions**. When you have multiple questions that are tightly related to one another it is okay to put them in one SO question, but when you have questions that are not tightly related to one another, they should be in different SO questions.

Comment: Okay louis..i shall follow the approach henceforth. Apologies!! i am new to SO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to scroll to element using selenium webdriver. If you want to perform some operation on element which is placed somewhere at the bottom of the page, then selenium will scroll page and click on element (or perform another action);

Selenium-webdriver uses promises (see [this documentation](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/javascript/class_webdriver_WebElement.html)  for more info to return values of element/it's attributes so if you want to get some element/or value of it's attribute you need to do next:

```
driver.findElement(webdriver.By.css("some selector")).then(function(elem){
    //e.g. return text in element
      return elem.getText().then(function(text){
            expect(text).toBe("your text");
      });
})
```

You don't need to use any particular method in selenium to wait until text is changed, just create loop which will look for value in element for some amount of time.

Comment: Hi andrey..thanks a lot for your reply..one doubt I had was ,the text is not present in the html element's text attribute. Instead it looks like this <td class="ng-binding">FAILED</td> what do we do then ?

Comment: Could you provide part of html with your elements, and selectors which you use to find necessary element? If you need to take text from td element then all is very simple `driver.findElement(webdriver.By.css(".ng-binging")).then(function(elem){ return elem.getText().then(function(text){ expect(text).toBe("FAILED"); });})`

Comment: <tr class="ng-scope" ng-repeat="list in pagedItems[currentPage] | orderBy:predicate">

    <td class="ng-binding">

        Offline

    </td>
    <td class="ng-binding">

        2014-08-21T09:30:03.039Z

    </td>
    <td class="ng-binding">

        FAILED

    </td>
    <td></td>

</tr>
so this is the html and I am using the xpath "html/body/section/section/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]" to access it

Comment: If I wanted to read the text "FAILED" now programmatically.. how would i do that.. thanks a lot for your time Andrey

Comment: see my previous answer, this should help you to get text in "td class=ng-binding"